# Dataflow graphs no longer updating correctly

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

We've just noticed that the job graph in the developer console no longer shows the side inputs as being successfully read/loaded, and the number of "records read" now displays "0". They used to display green and have a "succeeded" status, but now they just show "unknown".

What's happened to the dataflow graphs?

Job ID: **2015-05-05_17_36_52-10252445076674311417**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

We've identified a bug in the monitoring UI, and will be rolling out a fix soon.  Thanks for the report!

Comment: The status "Succeeded" is back, but it still shows 0 records that were read.